# Why couldn't I boot Android emulator with Android 6.0 configuration?

Tags: android

I want to test my Android App on different Android API levels, but when I setup my AVD to Android 6.0(API level 23), I found it couldn't boot up, and the log always show the following errors:

```
08-14 16:39:26.311  1193  1193 F DEBUG   : 
08-14 16:39:26.311  1193  1193 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_04
08-14 16:39:26.319  5369  5369 F DEBUG   : 
08-14 16:39:26.319  5369  5369 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_05
08-14 16:39:26.319  5369  5369 E         : ptrace detach from 5455 failed: No such process
08-14 16:39:26.319  5369  5369 E         : debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
08-14 16:39:26.323  1184  1184 I ServiceManager: service 'media.audio_flinger' died
08-14 16:39:26.323  1184  1184 I ServiceManager: service 'media.player' died
08-14 16:39:26.323  1184  1184 I ServiceManager: service 'media.resource_manager' died
```

Who could help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Please consider using formatting tools to make your logs/excerpts more readable.

Comment: user919426, I couldn't paste enough log contents when I formatting my log statements with your formatting tools, it forces me to add more explanations, so I removed many log information this time. but I fear these logs are not enough to describe my problem. Can you permit met to paste longer codes sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the root cause of this problem, and find a suitable workaround.

This is a serious bug in AndroidSDK latest official release:(android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz)
And it could only be triggered when we choosing the CPU as Intel Atom (X86_64), and the target as Android 6.0-API Level 23. No matter how long time you wait, your emulator couldn't boot correctly, you'll keep seeing the above log output repeatedly.

My workaround is changing the CPU choice from "Intel Atom (X86_64)" to "Intel Atom (X86)". Then the emulator could boot correctly.

It seems AndroidSDK release team doesn't test this case before they make the SDK release.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the answer, if you are answerd.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Genymotion Emulator.